# how can i edit a json column before saving in database

Tags: laravel

i am creating a booking and i want to add logedd User name to comment column ,
comment column is json field in database

```
"booking": {
        "package_id": 4,
        "email": "jio@gmail.com",
        "phone": 9898989898,
        "country_code": 92,
        "no_of_days": "2",
        "total_cost": "5000",
        "total_discount": "5000",
        "total_gst": "5000",
        "total_amount_to_pay": "3000",
        "comment":"hiii",
}
$booking['comment']->setAttribute(auth()->user()->name, $booking->comment);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, in Booking model, you cast comment field to array:

```
class Booking extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'commment' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
$booking->comment = ['user_name' => auth()->user()->name, 'content' => 'hiii']
$booking->save();
```